# I'm running flutter webview but it gives an error while loading the page

Tags: flutter, webview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WzBW.png)

I add and run the flutter webview package, but it gives an error while loading the page. It looks like this on the emulator. When I install the apk on a normal phone, the problem does not appear. Website: https://gelirgelsin.com/ Why might it be doing this? Internet permission added in Android manifest.